# Call a function with true value if checkbox is checked and function with false value when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

I have a simple checkbox input

```
<input type="checkbox" name="xxx" data-ng-clik='someFunction(true/false)' "/>
```

If user tick checkbox I want to call my someFunction(true) with true value and if user uncheck I want to call the same function someFunction(false) with false value.

Any suggetions how can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should call your method on `ng-change` of checkbox, to get correct changed value. Also add `ng-model` to get two way binding enable your checkbox value.

```
<input ng-model="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" name="xxx" 
       ng-change='someFunction(myCheckbox)'">
```

Answer (score 0):

you got to use `ng-model` in the checkbox field

```
<input type="checkbox" name="xxx" ng-model="value" data-ng-click='someFunction(true/false)' "/>
```

So in your function, you can get it by using `$scope.value`